# Closing android default keyboard onClick of EditText

Tags: java, android, keyboard

Okay! So there are many answers to this question. But none of it worked for me. Maybe I am going wrong somewhere.

What I want to do is that, I don't want the default android soft keyboard popping up when I click on my EditText.

Here is my xml file

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="INR"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            ></TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/indiaflag"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/secondText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:text=""
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for hiding the keyboard, I am using InputMethodManager to no show the keyboard on click of the EditText

```
secondText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.secondText);
 InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.showSoftInput(secondText, InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

I am using this code in OnCreate just after the declaration of the secondText, But this does not work. I even tried an alternate method of using the above code on setOnClickListener. But still no Success.

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
secondText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(secondText.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

Instead of

```
secondText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

use

```
 OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          switch (event.getAction()) {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              Layout layout = ((EditText) v).getLayout();
              float x = event.getX() + secondText.getScrollX();
              int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(0, x);
              if(offset>0)
                  if(x>layout.getLineMax(0))
                      secondText.setSelection(offset);     // touch was at end of text
                  else
                      secondText.setSelection(offset - 1);
              break;
              }
          return true;
          }
      };
      secondText.setOnTouchListener(otl);
```

Comment: Should I add it in onCreate or in setOnClickListener?

Comment: I tried what you suggested, and it worked like a charm. But the cursor vanishes away. What should I do to have the cursor but no keyboard?

Comment: What is mText in this?

Comment: Nope, It does not work for me. I don't get a cursor. Have commented out the setInputType and copy pasted your code instead.

Comment: Undo the change you did now and add `secondText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);` after `secondText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);`

Comment: Okay, So I undo the change and added the RawInputType line after setInputType. Surprisingly it brought the default soft keyboard back. Removing the RawInputType line makes it work but without cursor

Answer (score 1):

Use This function for hide keyboared

```
 public static void hide_keyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view == null) 
        view = new View(activity);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```